# What is the chance of getting same decimals of percentage 4 times in a row with RNG?

Tags: fractions, random, percentages, decimal-expansion, rngs

I was rolling some random percentage with RNG between 0 and 1; if you multiply the result to 100, you're getting the percentage between 0 and 100, decimal amount was 4. And then I got 0.7171% [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeynY.png), is that equal to 1 in 1,000,000 ?
Because 0.1% equal to 1/1,000.
0.01% = 1/10,000.
0.001 = 1/100,000.
0.0001% = 1/1,000,000.
So, getting same decimals 4 times equals to 1 in 1,000,000 ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is the chance of getting the same decimal 4 times in a row ? I think it's 1 in 1,000,000.

Comment: The last "add the percentage sign" step is done by you, and only conceptually. The RNG knows nothing about how you interpret your result. When you are generating a random number with 4 decimal places between 0 and 1, the probability is $1\over 10000$

Comment: Some random number generators will keep on returning the same random number unless you provide it with a different seed.

Comment: @WW1, The RNG can generate random number decimal amount up to 15.

Comment: @cr001, thank you, that's helped me.